# How to store value in XSL and syntax for-each?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

My request XML is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test123 class="test" version="str1234">
    <Header>
        <MYD>str1234</MYID>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Action method="Request" type="PROV">
            <Approval>
                <Approval1>1234567890</Approval1>
                <Linked123>
                    <XYZNumber>12345</XYZNumber>
                </Linked123>
                <Version>123</Version>
                <Country level="12"  hasModified="true" isSelected="true">
                    <Year>1999</Year>
                    <Month>Jan</MonthShortName>
                </Country>
                <Version>123</Version>
                <Country level="12"  hasModified="true" isSelected="true">
                    <Year>1990</Year>
                    <Month>May</MonthShortName>
                </Country>
            </Approval>
        </Action>
    </Body>
</test123>
```

My question is in XSL  if field "version" is blank and "Approval1" is blank etc, then I will store all the error (my customise message) for every field in common variable and at the end I will return that variable value to forward requester, so that I will get the consolidated all the error in single variable and return back to user.

And also: how can I use `for-each` for the field of "country level" as it is repeating two times?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - For this above  xml , I have to generate XSL  and inside the XSL i am doing validation of fieldS and checking if they are empty or not.
So suppose more than more than 2 fields are empty than i will  store error message for the both  the fields in single variable .Reason :I have to give consolidate error to requester and want to tell him that all these fields are empty ,please check and get back to us with proper xml.

2nd question:-I am getting error while for each loop.I want to use for each after  "<Country level="12"  hasModified="true" isSelected="true">" ,

Comment: Please show us (a) your desired output, and (b) your best attempt at writing the code to produce it. No-one wants to write the code for you, but we're happy to help you get over whatever problem you are having: to see what that problem is, we need to see how far you got on your own.

Comment: @michael.hor257k -  I have updated my question , pleaserespond on that  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39304301/issue-with-foreach-in-xsl

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice. Edit your question here.

Comment: Please copy the new parts of your question back here, thanks.