# Issue with foreach in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Processtype class="test" version="str1234">
 <Header>
 <MYID>str1234</MYID>
 </Header>
 <Body>
  <Action method="Request" type="PROV">
 <Approval>
 <FirsApproval>1234567890</FirstApproval1>
 <Linked123>
 <PONumber>12345</PONumber>
 </Linked123>
 <Version>123</Version>
 <Country level="12"  hasModified="true" isSelected="true">**
 <Year>1999</Year>
 <Month>Jan</MonthShortName>
 </Country>
 <Version>123</Version>
 <Country level="12"  hasModified="true" isSelected="true">
 <Year>1990</Year>
 <Month>May</MonthShortName>
 </Country>
 </Approval>
 </Action>
 </Body>
 </Processtype>
```

For this above XML , i have to generate XSL and do some validation(like field is not empty ) inside the xsl .Below is  my XSL file which i was generated from Above XML.

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/ProcessType">
<xsl:choose>

         <xsl:when test= "./Body/Action/approval/FirstApproval='' ">Invalid XML-FirstApproval field is blank   </xsl:when >
         <xsl:when test= "./Body/Action/PONumber='' ">Invalid XML- PO numumber field is blank  </xsl:when >

        <xsl:otherwise>Valid XML</xsl:otherwise>

 </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am succefully doing validation for these fields which are not repeating but for below part  i want to use foreach (for  this below part only , it is the part of above xml) because it it is repeating two times

```
      <Country level="12"  hasModified="true" isSelected="true">**
       <Year>1999</Year>
       <Month>Jan</MonthShortName>
        </Country>
        <Country level="12"  hasModified="true" isSelected="true">
       <Year>1990</Year>
       <Month>May</MonthShortName>
          </Country>
```

First query:-How to use foreach for this above portion with my existing xsl code

Second query:-I want store above error in single variable (i.e Invalid XML-FirstApproval field is blank), so that I will revert back to user (WITH THAT VALUE OF VARIABLE) 
    and tell him that in your xml these fields are showing error and please 
   correct these fields value and revert back with correct xml.

Please advice.

Many Thnaks,
  Sc

Comment: Your XML contains `Processtype` but your XSL looks for `ProcessType`. XSL/XPath is case-sensitive, please fix that first.  Also the indentation of your XSL and XML are messed-up. Please pick an indentation style (for example "two spaces") and use it consistently, at least for the question here.

Comment: @Tomalak  that is type eeor it was correct in mu actual code (I have checked now ) the only issue I am facing to use foreach only.

Comment: @Tomalak  

Please also advice for 2nd query.